# How can I load txt file from internet into my jsf app?

Tags: java, jsf, urlconnection, bufferedreader

It's me again) I have another problem. I want to load file (for example - txt) from web. 
I tried to use the next code in my managed bean:

```
 public void run() 
 {
  try
  {
   URL url = new URL(this.filename);
   URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
   bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
   if (bufferedReader == null) 
   {
    return;
   }

   String str = bufferedReader.readLine();
   while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) 
   {
     System.out.println("---- " + bufferedReader.readLine());
   }
 }
  catch(MalformedURLException mue)
  {
   System.out.println("MalformedURLException in run() method");
   mue.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch(IOException ioe) 
  {
   System.out.println("IOException in run() method");
   ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
   finally 
   {
     try
     {
       bufferedReader.close();
     }
     catch(IOException ioe) 
     {
       System.out.println("UOException wile closing BufferedReader");
       ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
 }


  public String doFileUpdate() 
  {
   String str = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestServletPath();
    System.out.println("111111111111111111111  str = " + str);
    str = "http://narod.ru/disk/20957166000/test.txt.html";//"http://localhost:8080/sfront/files/test.html";
    System.out.println("222222222222222222222  str = " + str);
    FileUpdater fileUpdater = new FileUpdater(str);
    fileUpdater.run();

    return null;
  }
```

But the BufferedReader returns the html code of the current page, where i am trying to call managed bean's method.
It's very strange thing - I have googled and none have had this problem.

Maybe I do something wrong, maybe there us a simplest way to load file into web (jsf) app not using net API. Any ideas?

Thanks very much for help!

**Update**:

Maybe some jsf code will be useful:

```
     <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:fc="http://www.fusioncharts.com"
                xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk"
                template="template.xhtml">
       <ui:define name="title">Add company page</ui:define>
       <ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="addCompanyForm">
            <h:outputText value="Add a new company"/><br/><br/><br/>
            <div style="width: 400px;">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="1">
                            Company name:
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputText id="companyName" value="#{companyBean.companyName}" style="width: 100%;" required="true" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
                            Company description:&#160;
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h:inputTextarea value="#{companyBean.companyDescription}" style="width: 100%;"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br/>
                <center>
                    <h:commandButton value="Save company" action="#{companyBean.doInsertCompany}" style="width: 40%;"/>&#160;&#160;
                    <a4j:commandButton ajaxSingle="true" value="Clear" actionListener="#{companyBean.doClear}" style="width: 40%;" reRender="addCompanyForm"/>
                </center>
                <br/><br/><br/>

                <h:commandLink value="Return to companies page" action="companies" immediate="true" />

            </div>
        </h:form>

        <h:form>
            <br/>
            <h:commandButton value="File Update" action="#{companyBean.doFileUpdate}" style="width: 10%;"/>&#160;&#160;
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

**Update 2**: I take another file from web (not localhost) - and everything works fine! Sorry for beying crazy about this)))

As BalusC said, my app just didnt find file by URL: http://localhost:8080/sfront/files/test.txt.

I dont know why I could not use local files.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need some code formating...

Comment: I formatted some code. @Elena: please pay attention to formatting rules in right hand column while editing message and also make use of the preview section at the bottom of the page to check if everything looks good.

Comment: Thanks for helping))) 
What code did you formated? In my broweser (Opera 10.53) everything looks good. For source code I do 4 spaces (even more). Could you tell me, what was wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want to include this in your JSF page, then I suggest you to use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`c:import`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/import.html) for this.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:import url="http://narod.ru/disk/20957166000/test.txt.html" />
```

Much easier. This however only works if you're using JSF on JSP. This won't work with JSF on Facelets and it (unfortunately) also doesn't offer simliar facilities.

As to your actual problem: I have no idea since the described problem is caused outside the scope of the as far posted code information or you didn't run the code you expect it was running (restart the webserver to make sure that latest changes to Java code get compiled). At least the `this.filename` returned the incorrect value and I see that you've the URL of your own webpage outcommented. Maybe you changed this but the hotdeploy failed or the server wasn't restarted before testing.

Further I see that you're only printing every second line from `BufferedReader` and ignoring every first alternating line.

```
while (bufferedReader.readLine() != null) // You're ignoring first line.
{
   System.out.println("---- " + bufferedReader.readLine()); // You're only printing next line.
```

This ain't going to work. Assuming that you want the file in a single big `String`, then you should follow the following idiom to use `BufferedReader#readLine()` properly:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
StringBuider builder = new StringBuilder();
try {
     reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(someInputStream, "UTF-8"));
     for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
         builder.append(line).append("\n"); // Append newline as well since readLine() eats them.
     }
} finally {
     if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
}
String content = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Hi, BalusC! Thanks for quick answer!
I will try your suggestion in a few minutes. 

Now I will try to explain what I need - I need a method, which will recieve the URL of some file (it could be txt file, xls, sql) as a parameter and I want to read information in that file and proccess it later.
But instead of information in that file I receive the source code of the current page.

Comment: Yes, I already understood that. This just means that the URL is wrong. Check the value of `this.filename`. Or restart the server.